# Is there a standard way to do contract-first web service endpoints for iOS clients?

Tags: ios, swift, web-services

I'm responsible for a project that is producing the server backend for an iOS application.

I would like to formally define the service interface for the clients to call so both the IOS, Android and server teams can practice contract-first development.

In the dark past we would have used WSDL and generated RPC-style client and server interop boilerplate from that. However this isn't the norm for IOS projects. We've also looked at Apache Thrift, but there is no code generator for Swift and the Objective-C generator seems to produce code that relies on deprecated IOS APIs.

Which brings us to REST, which works well as a way to move object state around. It seems less good for the kind of conversation that says "Hey server, do X with these parameters and return me a result." We just end up creating server-side controllers for particular actions, and those "define" the service's calling convention by being sticklers for getting the right parameters. Contract-last.

**Is there a standard way to do contract-first web service development for iOS clients, or am I just going to have to treat documentation as the spec?**

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: No.

> I'm not aware of a 'standard' way of doing things, but many
>   client/server apps today do use some incarnation of a RESTful
>   interface. JSON is the usual format.
>
> There are some well documented 3rd party utilities that can handle
>   this for you client side (like [RESTKit][1] in the case of REST), or
>   you can roll your own implementation based on apple's provided
>   `NSURLSession` or a networking library like [AFNetworking][2]
>
> If needed, iOS can also handle socket-based communication. (3rd party
>   libs exist for this as well.)
>
> [1]: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit   [2]:
>   http://nshipster.com/afnetworking-2/

Comment: The problem with REST is that the *specification* of the client-server interface is ad-hoc. I'm looking for some form of interface definition language.

Also, when you have a server side action like "sendConfirmationToken", I am unsure of how to expose that in a RESTful manner. Just using JSON as the request body doesn't make something RESTful.

Comment: well then, the answer is no. I'll update my answer to reflect that.